# C++ declaring double-linked list, traverse list both ways with two for-loops and print

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

Just beginning with C++ (be gentle, please). I have some code and I have to:

- Add Element* to make doubly-linked list
- Add insert_before() and insert_after() methods to Element
- Traverse list both ways with two separate for-loops
- Print operating number inside each loop

**Code**

I tried the following:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Element {
    Element* next{};
    Element* previous{};

    void insert_after(Element* new_element) {
        new_element -> previous = this;
        new_element -> next = this -> next;
        this -> next = new_element;
    }
    void insert_before(Element* new_element) {
        new_element -> previous = this -> previous;
        new_element -> next = this;
        this -> previous = new_element;
    }
    char prefix[2];
    short operating_number;
};

int main() {
    Element trooper1, trooper2, trooper3, trooper4;
    trooper1.prefix[0] = 'T';
    trooper1.prefix[1] = 'K';
    trooper1.operating_number = 421;
    trooper1.insert_after(&trooper2);
    trooper2.prefix[0] = 'F';
    trooper2.prefix[1] = 'N';
    trooper2.operating_number = 2187;
    trooper2.insert_before(&trooper3);
    trooper3.prefix[0] = 'L';
    trooper3.prefix[1] = 'S';
    trooper3.operating_number = 005;
    trooper3.insert_before(&trooper4);
    trooper4.prefix[0] = 'F';
    trooper4.prefix[1] = 'K';
    trooper4.operating_number = 2602;

    for (Element *cursor = &trooper1; cursor; cursor = cursor -> next) {
        printf("stormtrooper %c%c-%d\n",
                cursor->prefix[0],
                cursor->prefix[1],
                cursor->operating_number);
    }
    for (Element *cursor = &trooper3; cursor; cursor = cursor -> previous) {
        printf("stormtrooper %c%c-%d\n",
               cursor->prefix[0],
               cursor->prefix[1],
               cursor->operating_number);
    }
}
```

It's very basic, I know. But I'm starting to learn.
The code compiles correctly but I get this output:

```
/home/facundo/Escritorio/C++Projects/cmake-build-debug/C__Projects
stormtrooper TK-421
stormtrooper FN-2187
stormtrooper LS-5
stormtrooper FK-2602
stormtrooper TK-421

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I really don't understand why it prints only that (I guess there should be 8 lines of output).
I was expecting an output that would print the elements like this:

trooper1

trooper4

trooper3

trooper2

trooper2

trooper3

trooper4

trooper1

Some help would be really appreciated. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: When you are inserting a node **between two nodes**, you need to update **4 pointers** (left's next, right's prev, and inserted's both next and prev). If you are inserting **at the beginning or at the end**, you need to update only **2 pointers**. You are updating 3 pointers without any recognition of these situations. I would recommend using pen and paper and draw all three situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `insert` functions, you are not linking up all the pointers correctly:

```
void insert_after(Element* new_element) {
    new_element -> previous = this;
    new_element -> next = this -> next;
    this -> next = new_element;
    if (new_element -> next)  // this check needed
        // to correctly link the next -> previous
        new_element -> next -> previous = new_element; 
}
```

and

```
void insert_before(Element* new_element) {
    new_element -> previous = this -> previous;
    new_element -> next = this;
    this -> previous = new_element;
    if (new_element -> previous) // this check needed
        // to correctly link the previous -> next
        new_element -> previous -> next = new_element;
}
```

Also, in the second `for` loop, note that `trooper2` is the last `Element` in the list, not `trooper3`, so you need to start from there to see all the `Element`s in reverse.

Here's a [demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/9s9TPv).